# Existence of a solution to a Cauchy's problem on an unbounded interval

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We know $f$ and $f'y$ are both functions continuous on $\mathbb{R^2}$. Then $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \leq k(x)$ where $k$ is also continuous. One needs to prove tha a solution for $$\left\{
  \begin{array}{l l}
    y' = f(x,y)\\
    y(x_0) = y_0
  \end{array} \right.$$ exists for $x_0 \leq x < \infty$

I have absolutely no idea what to do. I look at the Peano theorem, but this just doesn't  apply here, not explicitly at least. Then, I'm not really sure why are the assumptions helpful, especially the one with the partial derivative. Any hints?

Comment: You probably meant $|\partial f/\partial y|\le k(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an existence theorem with a quantitative estimate for the existence interval. Such a theorem is often called the [Picard–Lindelöf theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem) but is also associated with other names. In its [optimized form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem#Optimization_of_the_solution.27s_interval) it ensures the existence of solution in the interval $[x_0-a,x_0+a]$ provided that $f$ is locally Lipschitz with respect to $y$ (you have that), and there exists $b$ such that $a\le b/M$ where $$M=\max \{|f(x,y)|: |x-x_0|\le a,\  |y-y_0|\le b\}$$
This is a bit complicated to arrange because $M$ depends on $b$. We need some control on $f$ to make this happen. Observe that your assumptions imply
$$
|f(x,y)|\le |f(x,0)|+|y|\, k(x) \tag{1}
$$ 
Fix large $A$; on the interval $[x_0,x_0+A]$ the estimate $(1)$ says
$$
|f(x,y)|\le C_1+C_2 |y| 
$$

Therefore, around the point $(x_0,y_0)$ we can have an existence interval of size $$a=(C_1+C_2(|y_0|+1))^{-1}\quad \text{ with } b=1$$ Within this interval $|y|$ is bounded by $|y_0|+1$. Therefore, the next interval will have size $(C_1+C_2(|y_0|+2))^{-1}$, and so on... since the harmonic series diverges, the solution exists on all of $[x_0,x_0+A]$. And since $A$ was arbitrary, this proves the claim.

Comment: Wait, but how does my assumptions imply $(1)$? I don't see it yet.

Comment: Mean value theorem: $|f(x,y)-f(x,0)|\le \dots$

Comment: But I still don't get one thing. If the solution exists for $|x-x_0| \leq (C_1+C_2(|y_0|+1))^{-1}$ why do I need another, smaller interval (namely with $a=(C_1+C_2(|y_0|+2))^{-1}$?

Comment: You want a solution on the whole half-axis. The theorem gives you a small interval. So you apply it again and get another small interval, then another one... if the sum of their lengths is infinite, you won.

Comment: Yes, but it says the solution exists when $|x-x_0| \leq (C_1+C_2(|y_0|+1))^{-1}$, so with the next interval I'd have $|x-x_0| \leq (C_1+C_2(|y_0|+2))^{-1}$. But $(C_1+C_2(|y_0|+2))^{-1} \subset (C_1+C_2(|y_0|+1))^{-1}$ so what do I need it for?